# TFS And Nuget Auto Package restore

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

Does TFS 2010 support the new non-xml Automatic package restore introduced as of nuget 2.7. Or (as I suspect) is only for 2013 upwards.

Comment: This is about using/the functionality of a developer tool. As such, it is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF] and a better fit on [SO].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TFS 2010 is over 5 years old there is no new functionality added. So, no. It does not support any advances since its last update in 2011.

You should consider upgrading to TFS 2013 or preferably VSO as 2010 falls out of mainstream support in a few months.

http://nakedalm.com/its-that-time-again-get-ready-to-upgrade-to-tfs-2015/

If you are still on TFS 2010 I would question the competency of whomever is supporting TFS. That's a long time to be behind when there is no cost to upgrading but their time. If this is a common problem in your organisation then VSO would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I thought this to be the case. I understand your feelings as to why some people would be on 2010 but you'll find thats suprisingly common :) The reason for the question was to try and drive the organisation forward to 2013 at least.